# Add scrollbar to specific table inside HTM file

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am new to html, and css, my .htm file looks like this:

```
<HTML>  
    <table border="0" height="406px" ID="Table1"
        style="WIDTH: 725px; HEIGHT: 406px">
        <tr>
            <td width="372px" height="20px" valign="top"><img src="StarsStartPage_SEET_1_1.png"
                    style="clip: rect(50px, 50px, 50px, 20px);"></td>
            <td width="480px" valign="top" height="20px"><FONT size="1" face="Arial">
                    <P><br>&nbsp;</P>
                    <P>&nbsp;</P>
                    <P>&nbsp;</P>
                </FONT>
                <table ID="Table2" border="0" bordercolor="white" width="443" height="52px" cellspacing="0"
                    cellpadding="2" style="WIDTH: 360px">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="openproject" width="100%" align="left" valign="middle">
                            <A href="urn:$$newproject"><IMG src="NewProject_Normal.png" height="36" width="155" border="0" style="Z-INDEX: 0"></A>
                            <font face="Arial" size="4" color="white">=</font>&nbsp;
                            <A href="urn:$$close"><IMG src="Continue_Normal.png" height="36" width="155" border="0" align="top"></A>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px; width: 360px;" dir="ltr"><font face="Arial" size="4" color="black">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Recently used Projects:<br></font></p>
                <table ID="plist" border="0" height="0" cellspacing="0" datasrc="#clicklist"
                    style="WIDTH: 360px; HEIGHT: 26px, overflow:auto">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="projline" width="100%" align="left" valign="middle" style="margin-left: 16px;"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                                <a id="proj" href="urn:a"><span datafld="Name"
                                style="padding-left: 20px; line-height: 26px;"></span></a></font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table ID="plistgrey" border="0" height="0" cellspacing="0" datasrc="#greylist"
                    style="WIDTH: 360px; HEIGHT: 26px">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="projlinegrey" width="100%" align="left" valign="middle"><font size="3" face="Tahoma" color="DimGray">
                                <span style="margin-left: 20px;" datafld="Name"></span></font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</BODY>
```

How can I add a scrollbar specifically to the table table ID = "plist"? I tried with this line: style="WIDTH: 360px; HEIGHT: 26px, overflow:auto"> but it didn't work. Should I change it to div style?

Comment: @SimonM. Should I try this around a div element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add overflow-y:scroll if you want to have a scroll bar in your div and add also a height which is less than your div

CSS :

```
#plist{
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Should I set <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> directly above the </HEAD> tag?

Comment: You should call your css inside the HEAD tag

Comment: I am calling it just before the </head> but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: You mean overflow-y or the call of your css ?

Comment: You should look in the inspector what is the path that you are calling for style.css or you can put directly in html with `style="WIDTH: 360px; height:100px; overflow-y:scroll;"` but the best way is to call a css file

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your table in a `div` element to make it work:

## CSS:

```
#list-wrapper{
    height: 150px; // For demo purposes, limit the height of the div
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

## HTML:

```
<div id="list-wrapper">
  <table>
...
  </table>
<div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/dkev6hLv/)

Also, your markup is very broken, but i cannot find what is wrong just now, you should fix that, if you struggle please open another question.